# SAS: How to project sashelp.zipcode coordinates onto maps.states?

Tags: sas, maps

I would like to plot thousands of zip codes on a US map. The coordinates of sashelp.zipcode are latitude/longitude in degrees, and for maps.states they are unprojected latitude/longitude radians. If I convert the zip code coordinates to radians using:

```
x=atan(1)/45*x;
y=atan(1)/45*y;
```

and I draw a map using

```
data states;
   set maps.states;
   where state not in (2, 15, 72);
   x = -x; 
run;
```

The zip codes are plotted accurately, but of course the map is (slightly) distorted. I'd like to get that plump curvy version of the US map that you get when you project maps.states.

I'll confess the gproject procedure is a bit opaque to me. I've tried:

```
data zips; 
    set <dataset with 86,000 zip codes>; 
    where state not in (2, 15, 72, .); 
    function='symbol'; 
    size = .02; 
    text = "dot"; 
    xsys='2'; 
    ysys='2'; 
    hsys='3'; 
    when='a';
    color= "%hsv(100,100,100)";
    x=atan(1)/45*x;
    y=atan(1)/45*y;
    x=-x; 
run;

data states; 
    set maps.states;
    where state not in (2, 15, 72);  
run;

data combo; 
    set zips states; 
run; 

proc gproject data=combo
              out=comboproj;
   id state;
run;

data zipsproj mapproj; 
    set comboproj; 
    if when = "a" then output zipsproj; 
    if when = "" then output mapproj; 
run; 

proc gmap map=mapproj 
          data=mapproj 
          anno = zipsproj all;
   id state;
   choro state / nolegend levels=1;
run;
quit;
```

This gives me a sideways US map with all of  the zip coordinates out of range (**Edit** I fixed the range problem by multiplying zip coordinates by -1 as well, but the map is still sideways).

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: There's a lot of map examples here: http://robslink.com/SAS/Home.htm . Perhaps that may help you find the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're not telling the annotate system what kind of coordinates you have.  Remember, annotations don't have to only be in the coordinate system of the graph itself - they can also be placed in off-graph locations (such as custom axis labels, custom titles, etc.), and they can be given in percentages instead of actual coordinates (say, coloring the right 20% red and the left 20% green). You use the `xsys`, `ysys`, and if you specify height of the character, `hsys`.  2 means 'absolute, data values'; 3 means 'absolute, percent of graph area'.  See [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/085-31.pdf) for more information on what the coordinate systems are.

You also shouldn't be multiplying the state x's by -1, at least not in my setup.  Only the zip coord x should be multiplied by -1.  But if your setup requires that, of course go ahead and do that.

Finally, the map gets turned sideways by GPROJECT when it sees some values in the negative-x side of things.  That causes it to make an odd choice when it coes to PARALLEL1/2 (you can see in the log this happening).  Eliminate all of the non-US48 states (Guam, Micronesia, etc.) to get to just the lower 48.

Here's a final code that works for me:

```
data states;
   set maps.states;
   where state not in (2, 15, 72);
run;

data zips;
  set sashelp.zipcode;
     x=-1*x;

x=atan(1)/45*x;
y=atan(1)/45*y;
if state ne 2 and state ne 15 and state lt 60;
  when='a';
  function='symbol';
  text='dot';
  xsys='2';
  ysys='2';
  hsys='3';

run;

data combo; 
    set zips  states; 
run; 

proc gproject data=combo
              out=comboproj;
   id state;
run;

data zipsproj mapproj; 
    set comboproj; 
    if when = "a" then output zipsproj; 
    if when = "" then output mapproj; 
run; 

proc gmap map=mapproj 
          data=mapproj 
          anno = zipsproj all density=4 ;
   id state;
   choro state / nolegend levels=1;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and thorough response! It made me realize that I left out the annotate variables I was using. I added them to my original answer. The one thing I see that's different is that you specify the x1 = x and y1 = y, so I'll have to think more about what that is doing.

Comment: That's not doing anything, I was making sure I had the variables right (as SGPLOT annotate is what I know better and I forget one vs. the other).

Comment: In my revised answer you can see that I included xsys = '2', ysys='2' and hsys='3'. When researching I came across other people who were having a similar problem when there are a lot of data points, but no one ever found a solution. Do you get a sideways map if you plot all of the zipcodes as dots?

Comment: I get a sideways map if I don't multiply the zipcode X coordinate by -1 before converting to radians (you have to convert one or the other, doesn't matter which - but if you convert States and not Zips, then the labels end up backwards after GPROJECT).

Comment: If I run your exact code but remove the if statement (and change the function to "symbol" and text to "dot") I get a sideways map. I reset SAS to make sure it wasn't a previous setting.

Comment: It's getting projected sideways because of the negative X coordinates - GPROJECT sees those and makes a different decision on the PARALLELs.  Guam, Micronesia, the Marshall islands, the Mariana islands all cause this.

Comment: Add    `if state ne 2 and state ne 15 and state lt 60;` to the zips dataset and you'll get the right result, I think.

Comment: BINGO! I was taking out Hawaii, Alaska, and Puerto Rico, but I forgot about the zips for Guam, Virgin Islands, etc. Hooray! Would you mind modifying your answer to include information about removing those zip codes to make this work? I know others on the internet have been asking this question and I will definitely mark this as the answer.